# jQuery parsing HTML unexpectedly and wrongly

Tags: jquery, facebook, fbml, xfbml, facebook-fbml

So I have a non-[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) solution to this problem, but I would rather use jQuery if there is a way, and also I am very curious as to why this is happening.

I have a Facebook iframe application, and I am using [Facebox](http://famspam.com/facebox/) to dynamically load a some XFBML in an on-page pop-up.

Now the XFBML I have loading happens to be the `fb:serverfbml` tag, which creates an iframe pointed at Facebook and renders the FBML. Which essentially means I need to dynamically add the FBML and then re-parse the XFBML after I display the popup. So I have code that looks like:

```
var App = {};

App.inviteFBML = '\
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 300px; height: 225px;"> \
    <script type="text/fbml">  \
        <fb:fbml>  \
        </fb:fbml>\
    </script>\
</fb:serverfbml>';

App.inviteFBMLHolder = "<div id='invite_holder' style='width: 300px; height: 250px;'></div>";

App.showInvitePrompt = function(){
    $.facebox(App.inviteFBMLHolder); 
    document.getElementById('invite_holder').innerHTML = App.inviteFBML;
    FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomElement(document.getElementById('facebox'));
};
```

Now the above code works, however notice that I am using

```
document.getElementById('invite_holder').innerHTML
```

rather than

```
$('#invite_holder').html();
```

If I use jQuery's `.html` function it actually restructures my HTML before inserting it. It restructures it to the following:

```
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 300px; height: 225px;"> 
</fb:serverfbml>
<script type="text/fbml">  
    <fb:fbml>  
    </fb:fbml>
</script>
```

I assume it is doing this because it contains non-standard tags, but is there any way to have jQuery not reformat my string before inserting it?

Comment: Someone might want to rename the title for this as it is not html being parsed incorrectly but rather a proprietary Facebook format.

Comment: ... but it *is* being parsed incorrectly... part of FBML implementation involves adding an xmlns:fbml declaration to the <html> element, so it is valid.

Comment: Does adding an xml namespace to a html document, then using xml tags from said xml namespace make the tags valid html?  Certainly this stuff wouldn't validate.

Comment: @ironsam, it makes it valid xml/xhtml, and yes, it should validate.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively it's jQuery's HTML parser that messes things up. So if you set the `innerHTML` manually it'll work fine.

So you can load it all in using:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url: "/my/url",
  datatype: 'text',
  success: function(html) {
    var ele = $('myselector')[0];
    ele.innerHTML = html;
    FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomElement(ele);
  }
});
```

The only issue with this is that none of the JavaScript code included in the HTML will be run upon insertion.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomElement(document.getElementById('facebox'));` to parse the added html. I'm hazarding a guess that the function should be looking for simple text. You can try adding the stuff as text rather than HTML using jquery like:

```
$('#invite_holder').text(App.inviteFBML);
```

Comment: Nice try, however using .text will escape any html characters that should normally be escaped in text. Thus instead of getting render-able xfbml, I get a text version of my html

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something similar, had the same issues with jQuery rearranging my code, but I was able to get around it by doing the following:

```
<fb:serverfbml id="fbml">
</fb:serverfbml>

<script type="text/javascript">
function populateInviteFbml() {
    $('#fbml').load('/getinvitefbml', null, renderInvite); // gets the FBML from <script type="text/fbml"> on in
}

function renderInvite() {
   FB_RequireFeatures(['XFBML'], function() {
         FB.Facebook.init('abcdabcdabcdabcd', '/xd_receiver.htm');
            });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery is much more lenient with what is created inside a `<script>` tag versus what normal html tags not in a script block.  You could create the outer non-html tag first with an id and then append to that:

```
$(".inner").append("<fb:serverfbml id='someID' style='width:300px; height: 225px;'>");
$("#someID").append("<script type='text\fbml'><fb:fbml></fb:fbml></script>");
```